# PHP - slow page load when looping results from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pageload, page-load-time

I have php code which fetches results from MySQL database - names of toys (in `toys` table) for `users` and **counts of toys and unique users** and displays on webpage.

The names of toys can be either one word or combination of words. We want to fetch those results from `toys` which has `toys_text` field having all the words of the word combinations from `words` table (example - If `words` table has entry called `blue car` - BOTH `blue` and `car` should be present in the `toys` table `toys_text` field for a match). The database changes over time with new toys with their users being added and outdated toys with their users removed.

The resulting page is very slow loading, taking around than 10 seconds in GT-metrix test. Google Analytics says issue with my code. My code is having subquery as follows -

```
<?php
$WordQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY `words`.`words` ASC");

$i = 1;
    while($row = $WordQ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){                      
        $Word = $row['words'];
        $WordsArr = explode(" ", $row['words']);

        $query = "";
        if(count($WordsArr) > 1){
          $query = "SELECT t_id,name,toys_text FROM toys WHERE toys_text 
        LIKE '%".implode("%' AND toys_text LIKE '%", $WordsArr)."%'";
        }else{
            $query = "SELECT t_id,name,toys_text FROM toys WHERE toys_text 
        LIKE '%$WordsArr[0]%'";
                    }
        $countIds = array();
        $countNames = array();
        $Data = $db->query($query);
        while($data = $Data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $countIds[] = $data['t_id'];
        $countNames[] = $data['name'];
                    }                       
        ?>                  
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['words'];?></td>
            <td><a href="showtoys.php?word=<?php echo urlencode($Word); ?
            >" target="_blank"><?php echo count(array_unique($countIds)); ?>
            </a></td>
            <td><a href="showtoys.php?word=<?php echo urlencode($Word); ?
            >" target="_blank"><?php echo count(array_unique($countNames)); 
            ?></a></td>
          </tr>
            <?php $i++;} ?>
```

I tried to remove the subquery but still the page is slow loading. Please guide how to make the page load faster. Following is the code without subquery -

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY `words`.`words` 
ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$i = 1;         
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                      
        $Word = $row['words'];
        $WordsArr = explode(" ", $row['words']);
        $query = "";
           if(count($WordsArr) > 1){
               $query1 = "select COUNT(*) as 'count', COUNT(DISTINCT 
               t.name) AS 'cnt' from toys t WHERE toys_text LIKE '%".implode("%' AND 
               toy_text LIKE '%", $WordsArr)."%'";
            }else{
            $query1 = "select COUNT(*) as 'count', COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) AS 
           'cnt' from toys t WHERE 
            toys_text LIKE '%$WordsArr[0]%'";
            }               
            $Data1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
            $total1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Data1);                       
                ?>                  
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['words'];?></td>
              <td><a href="showtoys.php?word=<?php echo 
              urlencode($Word); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo 
              $total1['count']; ?></a></td>
              <td><a href="showtoys.php?keyword=<?php echo urlencode($Word); 
              ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $total1['cnt']; ?></a></td>                    
            </tr>
                <?php $i++;} ?>
```

This is my MySQL tables structure -

**words :**

S.No    Name    Type

1. id Primary  int(11)
2. words   varchar(60)

   example - white car, balloon, blue bus
3. type    enum('words', 'phrase')

**toys :**

S.No.   Name    Type

1. t_id Primary    bigint(20)
2. toys_text FULLTEXT Index    varchar(255)
3. user_id BTREE Index bigint(20)
4. name BTREE Index    char(20)

The Mysql is 10.1.30-MariaDB with InnoDB storage.

**Edit -**

Say I have in `words` table, toy named as `little blue car`. Then true matches will be - 
I have a `little` `car` which is `blue`.
My `little` `car` of `blue` color is very fast.

False matches will be -

I have a little car.
My little car is very nice.

Meaning that all the words should be present in the `toys_text` field for a true match.

I changed the query to

```
if(count($WordsArr) > 1){ 
$query1 = "select COUNT() as 'count', 
COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) AS 'cnt' from toys t WHERE MATCH (toys_text) AGAINST 
('".implode("'+'", ($WordsArr))."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"; 
}else{ 
$query1 = "select COUNT() as 'count', COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) AS 'cnt' from 
toys t WHERE MATCH (toys_text) AGAINST ('%$WordsArr[0]%')";
```

Now, it is giving 0 counts for words having high number of counts and for word combinations. Those words are not in the stoplist of Mysql. Is this some restriction of FULLTEXT search ?

Comment: A FULLTEXT index doesn't mean that you can just use wildcards everywhere, you need to use [`MATCH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). *That* is why your queries are slow.

Comment: @Sammitch FULLTEXT search is not suitable here since the toy name combination may consist of 3 or more words

Comment: Yes it is. Keep reading the docs, specifically the return value of `MATCH()` and `BOOLEAN MODE`.

Comment: @Sammitch I changed the query to  **if(count($WordsArr) > 1){
               $query1 = "select COUNT(*) as 'count', COUNT(DISTINCT 
               t.name) AS 'cnt' from toys t WHERE MATCH (toys_text) AGAINST ('".implode("'+'", ($WordsArr))."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
            }else{
            $query1 = "select COUNT(*) as 'count', COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) AS 
           'cnt' from toys t WHERE 
            MATCH (toys_text) AGAINST ('%$WordsArr[0]%')";** Now, it is giving 0 counts for words having high number of counts and for word combinations. Is this some restriction of FULLTEXT search ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Sammitch, changed query with MATCH() in boolean mode with foreach loop. Now, the page is loading in one third time , about 3 seconds.

This is my code -

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY `words`.`words` 
ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$i = 1;            
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                        
    $Word = $row['words'];
    $WordsArr = explode(" ", $row['words']);
    $query = "";

       if(count($WordsArr) > 1){
          foreach ($WordsArr as $value) {
                    $value1='';
                    $value1 .= " +"."(".$value."*".")";
                    }
           $query1 = "select COUNT(*) as 'count', COUNT(DISTINCT 
           t.name) AS 'cnt' from toys t WHERE MATCH (toys_text) AGAINST 
          ('$value1' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
        }else{
        $query1 = "select COUNT(*) as 'count', COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) AS 
       'cnt' from toys t WHERE 
        MATCH (toys_text) AGAINST ('$WordsArr[0]* IN BOOLEAN MODE')";
        }               
        $Data1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
        $total1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Data1);                     
            ?>                  
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['words'];?></td>
          <td><a href="showtoys.php?word=<?php echo 
          urlencode($Word); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo 
          $total1['count']; ?></a></td>
          <td><a href="showtoys.php?keyword=<?php echo urlencode($Word); 
          ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $total1['cnt']; ?></a></td>                   
        </tr>
            <?php $i++;} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the PHP loop that executes sql requests. So to reduce the time you shouldn't do a lot of request but the strict minimum. In your case, it's a little hard to find the clean way but it should have one!

There is maybe a way by creating a view of all word (one by one) of your "toys" table, with the sql Substring function. Then the subquery function is not a "like" but a simple "=", which is far more faster.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-view/

Comment: Never used this. Can you please update your post with actual code ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use stored procedure to make your query faster, because you used 
 a while loop then you have another query inside it. it is more faster if you just call a procedure than building the query in php.

try to check this link for references: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines.html

i guarantee you that it will make a smooth query.

and if you just need to get the count of those toys that consist the word
i suggest to just query all in the first part before the while loop using Join then count them and just group them by the word.

```
$stringWord= str_replace(' ', '%', $WordsArr);

$query1 = "call toysQuery(".$stringWord.")";
```

then in your procedure parameter use varchar.

Comment: FULLTEXT search is not suitable here since the toy name combination may consist of 3 or more words

Comment: in that case you should query the words then each of the word just change the value of spaces into a percent sign (%) then put it in your procedure parameter as text then use it in your query. check my code above

Comment: Say I have in `words` table, toy named as `little blue car`. Then true matches will be - 
I have a `little` `car` which is `blue`.
My `little` `car` of `blue` color is very fast.

False matches will be - 

I have a little car.
My little car is very nice.

Meaning that all the words should be present in the `toys_text` field of `toys` table for a true match.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating and runniing SQL from the output of an SQL statement in a loop. Just do a join between the queries, one round trip to the database, one loop to display the results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried to make one query but then the results do not appear. @symcbean can you please put give some code with your advice. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, the two tables cannot be joined because there is no common column

Comment: They have common data. The right way to fix the problem is to normalize your data (there are ways to get the results from the existing schema faster with full text indexexing but that's not a scalable approach)

Comment: Please see my question. There is no common column between the `words` and `toys` table. So, it is not possible to join these tables

Comment: You are extracting data from one table and using it as a predicate for querying another table - that's a join, albeit a very inefficient one.

Comment: For example, in `words` table, I have an entry `little blue car` . Then I split the words and search for them in `toys_text` field of `toys` table. Then true matches will be - I have a little car which is blue. My little car of blue color is very fast.False matches will be -

I have a little car. My little car is very nice.

Meaning that all the words should be present in the toys_text field for a true match. I do not see how these tables can be joined together.